# QT5 : best efficiant way to "unserialise" array of keys/values from json result

Tags: php, mysql, json, qt

I begin in QT, and it's a nightmare to get data back from php (to send mysql result)

PHP side :

```
...
$rs = mysql_query( $sql );
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)) { 
    $result[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode(array('code'=>'OK', 'result' => $result));
```

witch give the following result :

```
{"code":"OK","result":
[{"CCMGD_HOUR":"19980","CCMGD_DAY":"3"},
{"CCMGD_HOUR":"32400","CCMGD_DAY":"3"},
{"CCMGD_HOUR":"71100","CCMGD_DAY":"3"},
{"CCMGD_HOUR":"71700","CCMGD_DAY":"3"},
{"CCMGD_HOUR":"72000","CCMGD_DAY":"3"}]}
```

Now, QT side :

```
...
QNetworkReply* reply;
QString data = (QString) reply->readAll();
QJsonDocument d = QJsonDocument::fromJson(data.toUtf8());
QJsonObject jo = d.object();

QVariantHash hash =  jo.toVariantHash();
QVariantList list = hash.value("result").toList();
```

But after ??? If I am good at this point, how to iterate trought rows and extract keys (CCMGD_HOUR and CCMGD_DAY)?

I find how to iterate:

```
foreach(const QVariant &item, result){
   ...//but item has 2 items for the row:
     [0]
       key "CCMGD_HOUR"
       value "19980" 
     [1]
       key "CCMGD_DAY"
       value "3" 

     how to extract this ?
}
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extract values from Json, try this

```
QJsonDocument document = QJsonDocument::fromJson(reply->readAll());
QJsonObject jo = document.object();
foreach (const QJSonValue& value, jo["result"].toArray()) {
  QJsonObject obj = value.toObject();
  qDebug() << "CCMGD_HOUR: " << obj["CCMGD_HOUR"].toInt();
  qDebug() << "CCMGD_DAY: " << obj["CCMGD_DAY"].toInt(); 
}
```

Comment: compiler complain at "foreach (const QJSonValue& value, jo["result"].toArray())" => invalid use of incomplete class QJsonArray

Comment: @user3183329 - you might have forgotten to include the header `#include <QJsonArray>`?

Comment: yes ... I didn't include it. It is working great ! and seem to be smart. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

To iterate on a index based list, you could do the following.

```
for (i = list.begin(); i != list.end(); ++i)
```

or

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i)
```

In your case, maybe you should use the `map` object instead (its an associative array).

`QVariant` as a `toMap` method : http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html#toMap

Then you can access the map object, the same way as you would in `PHP` with an assoc array : e.g `list["result"][0]["CCMGD_HOUR"]`

Comment: well, list is QVariantList, if I write this, compiler said "no match for operator [] (operator type are 'QVariant' and const char [9]", sorry I try with map

Comment: well, it is working QVariantList => Qmap, but seem a lot of operations